# Merging 2 strings together?

Tags: lua

I have two strings

```lua
String1 = "h l o w r d"
String2 = " e l   o l !"
```

I want to combine them so I will have a result like this:

`hello world!`

I don't know how to do that or what methods I have to use.

Comment: `string.sub` to extract characters in a loop, `table.concat` to concatenate them again, see https://www.lua.org/pil/11.6.html

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: Lua 5.1 if you want to know exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can read strings byte by byte, and compare characters like this:

```
local String1 = "h l o w r d"
local String2 = " e l   o l !"
local s = ""
local i = 1
repeat
   local b1, b2 = String1:byte(i), String2:byte(i)
   s = s .. string.char( (b2==nil or b1~=32)  and b1 or b2)
   i = i+1
   print(i,s)
until not (String1:byte(i) or String2:byte(i) )
```